# Add a Background Image for Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

New to Bootstrap and I'm trying to add a background image to the jumbotron. The image is not appearing.

I've uploaded the files here:
http://www.ashton.me/lab/practice001/

Here's my custom CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
  background-image: url('images/wormhole.jpg');
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: i checked the browser debbuger/developer tool, you have no css with that rule anywhere, please use the browser debugging tools. its free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I know what the problem is!
Change:

```
background-image: url('images/wormhole.jpg');
```

TO:

```
background-image: url('../images/wormhole.jpg');
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. So the path should be from the css file, not the html file.

Comment: Or use site-absolute paths: `/images/wormhole.jpg`. (Notice the starting `/`!)