# Background image for Jumbotron using Bootstrap doen't work for me

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have been trying to add a background image to the the jumbotron but the image isn't appearing.

I took the codes exactly from this link: http://www.bootply.com/103783

I  copied pasted the HTML , CSS and java I only changed the image path.

I have tried many other codes for image as a background on jumbotron. NOTHING worked I mean no image appeared. The image appeared once using the code I referred to but it is not behind the jumbotron , it appeared next to it or just somewhere on the page. Appreciate your help :(

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bootstrap Jumbotron</h1>
        <p class="lead">+ Parallax Effect using jQuery</p>
    </div>



</head>


    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background: url('2.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px; /*same height as jumbotron */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron {
    height: 350px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: #444 0 1px 1px;
    background:transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
var jumboHeight = $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('height', (jumboHeight-scrolled) + 'px');
}

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

Comment: Show YOUR code so we can diagnose. Looking at an example of something that works doesn't help us :) Also, I'm sure you mean JS.

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: yeah javascript hahaha ..I'm just new to these stuff ok I'll post mine

Comment: I'm going to bet that the path to your image is wrong, but without code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Right click over your page, choose inspect element, look at console tab. ( Not sure about IE on this ) see if you have any errors.

Comment: Your jumbotron code is inside the `head` element.

Comment: Is the file `2.jpg` in the same folder as the CSS? Also, as @Aibrean pointed out, you have HTML in your `head` element, it has to go in the body(you're also missing the opening `body` tag).

Comment: I did change the head thing still didn't work :( the image is in the directory of the whole project.

Comment: yes the css and the image are in the same directory if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path to image is correct in your css, the issue is that your markup is inside the `<head>` tag. Nothing in this tag is ever rendered to page.

Your markup structure should be :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!----- head stuff ----->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--- for semantic reasons you could wrap your jumbotron in a <header></header> tag --->
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Bootstrap Jumbotron</h1>
      <p class="lead">+ Parallax Effect using jQuery</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yup just did that @JustH when I render no image still.

Comment: then the likely cause is that the path to image is wrong. with your current code it needs to be in the same directory as your css file

Comment: The CSS file and the image are in the same place. The program I'm working with allows me to put all the files I'm working with in the same directory. check this out  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783060/add-a-background-image-for-bootstrap-jumbotron?rq=1

Comment: What program are you using? does it compile/output them to a different directory structure than you are starting with? ie does it automatically put all images in an /img/ directory or something like that?

Comment: I'm using Webstorm. I don't think so no it compiles and shows me the page only.